# Can't get connection with Docker using mongodb and express

Tags: mongodb, docker, express, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to set up docker in my projects to learn.

I have a nodejs project that uses Express + mongodb packs.

The Docker is configured ad running ok but when I need to create a connection, it returns undefinded. Its not a problem with the project code because when I start the server and the database service without the docker it works well.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/got/

WORKDIR /usr/src/got/

COPY package*.json /usr/src/got/

RUN npm i

COPY . /usr/src/app

RUN npm i -g --save-dev nodemon

EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "node", "app.js" ]
```

docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  app:
    build: .
    image: got:latest
    command: nodemon app.js
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/got/
    ports: 
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    links:
      - mongo

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    ports: 
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - data-volume:/data/db

volumes:
  data-volume:
```

error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined app_1    |
>   at /usr/src/got/app/models/usuariosDAO.js:8:12 app_1    |     at
>   /usr/src/got/node_modules/mongodb/lib/db.js:229:14

code where throws the error:
userDAO.js:

```
UserDAO.prototype.inserirUsuario = function (usuarioDTO) {
  this._conn.open(function(error, client) {

    client.collection('usuarios', function (error, collection) {
      collection.insert(usuarioDTO)
    })

  })
}
```

the connection config:

```
const mongoDbConnection =  function () {

  console.log('Connected to mongo database')

  const db = new mongo.Db(
    'got',
    new mongo.Server(
      '127.0.0.1',
      27017,
      {}
    ),
    {}
  )

  return db
}
```

Thanks...

Comment: where is the error? better to post error from express

Comment: Posted.. thanks for helping

Comment: You should use `mongo` as host instead of `127.0.0.1` if this config that you have shown is client config.

Comment: On the head nail you have hit mester @michalk. Thankyou very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `mongo` as host instead of `127.0.0.1`. Be default containers from compose are connected to a common network and service name from compose can be resolved by DNS to container IP :

```
const db = new mongo.Db(
    'got',
    new mongo.Server(
      'mongo',
      27017,
      {}
    ),
    {}
  )
```